# Why the fly camera never fly between waypoints over terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 scripts attached to a camera I called Fly Camera.
A bit long but all 3 scripts are working together:

First the script LookAtCamera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    //values that will be set in the Inspector
    public Transform target;
    public float RotationSpeed;

    //values for internal use
    private Quaternion _lookRotation;
    private Vector3 _direction;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //find the vector pointing from our position to the target
        if (target)
            _direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

        //create the rotation we need to be in to look at the target
        if (_direction != Vector3.zero)
            _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

        //rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

Next FlyToOverTerrain:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyToOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float desiredHeight = 10f;

    public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
    public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
    public float flightAcceleration = 1f;

    public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
    public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
    public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;

    private Vector3 flightVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    private float heightVelocity = 0f;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        float currentHeight = position.y;
        if (target && flightAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
        {
            position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(position, target.position, ref flightVelocity, flightSmoothTime / flightAcceleration, maxFlightspeed, flightAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (levelingAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
        {
            float targetHeight = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position) + desiredHeight;

            position.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentHeight, targetHeight, ref heightVelocity, levelingSmoothTime / levelingAcceleration, maxLevelingSpeed, levelingAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

And last PatrolOverTerrain:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PatrolData
{
    public Transform target = null;
    public float minDistance = 5f;
    public float lingerDuration = 5f;
    public float desiredHeight = 10f;
    public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
    public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
    public float flightAcceleration = 1f;
    public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
    public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
    public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;
}

public class PatrolOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FlyToOverTerrain flyOverTerrain;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCamera;
    public enum PatrolMode { Clamp, Wrap, PingPong };
    public PatrolData[] patrolPoints;
    public PatrolMode mode = PatrolMode.Wrap;

    private int iterator = 0;
    private int index = 0;
    private float lingerDuration = 0f;
    private int overallLength = 0;

    public bool autoFreedomPatrol = false;
    public List<GameObject> Targets = new List<GameObject>();
    public string tagName;
    public Vector3 distanceFromTarget;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (tagName != "")
        {
            GameObject[] tempObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tagName);

            for (int i = 0; i < tempObj.Length; i++)
            {
                //Add to list only if it does not exist
                if (!Targets.Contains(tempObj[i]))
                {
                    Targets.Add(tempObj[i]);
                }
            }

            //Get the current Size
            if (tempObj != null)
            {
                overallLength = Targets.Count;
            }

            GeneratePatrolPoints();
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (patrolPoints.Length > 0)
        {
            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        int length = patrolPoints.Length;
        if (!flyOverTerrain) return;
        if (patrolPoints.Length < 1) return;
        if (index < 0) return;

        var patrol = patrolPoints[index];
        if (lingerDuration <= 0)
        {
            iterator++;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case PatrolMode.Clamp:
                    index = (iterator >= length) ? -1 : iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.Wrap:
                    iterator = Modulus(iterator, length);
                    index = iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.PingPong:
                    index = PingPong(iterator, length);
                    break;
            }
            if (index < 0) return;

            patrol = patrolPoints[index];

            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            flyOverTerrain.desiredHeight = patrol.desiredHeight;
            flyOverTerrain.flightSmoothTime = patrol.flightSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxFlightspeed = patrol.maxFlightspeed;
            flyOverTerrain.flightAcceleration = patrol.flightAcceleration;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingSmoothTime = patrol.levelingSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxLevelingSpeed = patrol.maxLevelingSpeed;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingAcceleration = patrol.levelingAcceleration;

            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.RotationSpeed = 3;

            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }

        Vector3 targetOffset = Vector3.zero;
        if ((bool)patrol.target)
        {
            targetOffset = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
        }

        float sqrDistance = patrol.minDistance * patrol.minDistance;
        if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = null;
            lookAtCamera.target = null;
            lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
        }
        distanceFromTarget = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
    }

    private int PingPong(int baseNumber, int limit)
    {
        if (limit < 2) return 0;
        return limit - Mathf.Abs(limit - Modulus(baseNumber, limit + (limit - 2)) - 1) - 1;
    }

    private int Modulus(int baseNumber, int modulus)
    {
        return (modulus == 0) ? baseNumber : baseNumber - modulus * (int)Mathf.Floor(baseNumber / (float)modulus);
    }

    public void GeneratePatrolPoints()
    {
        patrolPoints = new PatrolData[Targets.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < patrolPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            patrolPoints[i] = new PatrolData();
            patrolPoints[i].target = Targets[i].transform;
            patrolPoints[i].minDistance = 30f;
            patrolPoints[i].lingerDuration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightSmoothTime = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxFlightspeed = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightAcceleration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingAcceleration = 2f;
        }
    }
}
```

The camera rotate facing the first waypoint but never move to the next one/s.
There are 4 Spheres as waypoints they are tagged as Target.
When running the game the camera rotate smooth slowly facing the first Sphere move to it but then stop there and never continue. It should move between all the Spheres and then start over again.

Comment: It seems that somewhere else in your scene those `Targets` objects get destroyed...

Comment: Is there btw a reason why you store all the values for each waypoint individual if they are the same values for each element anyway?

Comment: @derHugo That was true when I used my SphereBuilder script that instantiate objects. So now I'm not using it and just created 4 Cubes and tagged them as Target and now they are not destroyed and missing. But the Camera is moving only to the first Cube and not continue to the others. (That's why I also removed the screenshot in my question since the missing destroy problem is not relevant).

Comment: @derHugo Now they have the same values but when I'm using my script SphereBuilder or other instantiating script I have it's instantiating objects with random position and rotation and scale.

Comment: I ment values like `desiredHeight` `flightSmoothTime` `maxFlightSpeed` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in

```
if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
{
    flyOverTerrain.target = null;
    lookAtCamera.target = null;
    lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
    lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
}
```

You only reduce the `lingerDuration` once namely the frame you reach the first target.

So your

```
 if (lingerDuration <= 0)
```

will probably never match.

I guess you rather want to reducer it in every frame the `Update` runs so rather move it outside that block.

---

I'ld also suggest to rather use

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, patrol.target.position) <= patrol.minDistance)
```

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The problem was with my settings in the Inspector of the script Fly To Over Terrain. The variable Desired Height was set to 10 but the cubes was at Height 0. Once changing the Desired Height to 0 or either changing the cubes height to higher it's working perfect.